# Compactness of $A\subset \mathbb R$ w.r.t. two different topologies

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $d$ be the Euclidean metric and $d'$ be any other metric on $\mathbb R$. Let $A\subset \mathbb R$ be a closed and bounded subset with respect to $d'$. Then which is TRUE ?
>
> (A) $A$ is compact with respect to $d'$.
>
> (B) $A$ is compact only if $d=d'$.
>
> (C) $A$ is compact if and only if the topologies induced by $d$ and $d'$ are same.
>
> (D) $A$ is compact if and only if $d$ and $d'$ are equivalent.

$d$ is the usual metric on $\mathbb R$ so , if $d=d'$ then $A$ is compact, but the converse may not be true. So, option (B) is not true. Clearly option (A) is not true. But I am unable to prove whether the other two options are correct or NOT..

Comment: (C) is not true. For example, let $A=\mathbb R$ and let $d'=\min\{1,d\}$.

Comment: Isn't $(D)$ a re-statement of $(C)$?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli: I think that he means strong equivalence in (D).

Comment: @@ Shalop ): Is $\mathbb R$ compact w.r.t. $d'$ in your ex. ?

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: No, that's why it's a counterexample to (C).

Comment: How $\mathbb R$ is bounded ? @  Shalop

Comment: @S.Panja-1729: It is bounded with respect to $d'$. Every subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded with respect to $d'$, since $d'(x,y)\leq 1$ for all $x,y$.

Comment: @  Shalop) How you can show that $\mathbb R$ is bounded w.r.t. $d'$ ?

Comment: @  Shalop) So what will be the answer?

Answer (score 2):

None is true.

Define $s(x)=1$ if $x\geq 0$ and $s(x)=0$ if $x\leq 0$.

Now define $d'(x,y)=\sqrt{(|x|-|y|)^2+(s(x)-s(y))^2}$

This metric is the metric induced by $\mathbb R^2$ via the map $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^2$ given by $x\mapsto (|x|,s(x))$

The metric $d'$ is not equivalent to $d$, neither it induces the same topology ($(-\infty,0]$ is open)

howwver,  on $(-\infty,0)$ we have $d'=d$, so any compact set $A\subset (-\infty,0)$ is compact for both. This proves that $B),C)$ and $D)$ are false.

In order to contradict $A)$ it suffices to consider the discrete metric on $d'(x,y)=1$ for $x\neq y$ and $d(x,x)=0$. For that metric $[0,1]$ is not compact.

In general, a metric space is compact if and only if it is complete and totally boundend (tot. bound.= $\forall\varepsilon >0\exists$ a finite $\varepsilon$-net)

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space).

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the easiest way to produce a counter-example (and indeed I will not), but just to see *how* wrong (C) and (D) are consider the following. Let $\pi\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be any bijection and $d'(x,y)=d(\pi(x), \pi(y))$ then $(\mathbb R, d)$ and $(\mathbb R,d')$ are isometric spaces, so certainly closed and bounded sets are compact in $(\mathbb R, d')$. But the likelihood of the topologies on induced by them being the same (i.e. the identity function being a homeomorphism) is slim.